# How can I get the values of the form on my admin page

Tags: custom-component, administrator, component-params

I have a form on my admin page of my component, and I can edit the fields and save them.

When I load the page the saved fields show.

Say for example in a blog_category menu item.  I create a new menu item based on this and I add a new field to the XML.  I want to populate that field with two of the other fields.

So when I open my menu item to edit the values I want the value of my new field to say contain the title and the meta description.  How do I get the existing values?

Comment: Is it in a plugin, component or module?

Comment: It's a component

Comment: As a most-fundamental check, just start var_dumping all of the variables that are available and sift through that heap for the data that you want.  Start in the view/template with the printing to screen, but if it's not there then you may have to sniff through the higher layers for what you need and ensure that they are passed down to the view/template.  I'm not sure if we have enough detail to help you yet.

Comment: You probably don't and I am probably too inexperienced to give it to you.  So I can look through the variables in my model/controller/view but I don't think that helps.  I'll update my question to be relevant to the core.